# singleton autofac property is null after binding

Tags: .net, singleton, autofac

i have question regarding autofac. i am having a bootstrap class where i am registering my viewmodel as singleton via registertyp().singleinstance().

```
mytype.singletong.listproperty() == populatedata;
```

then in my xaml i am binding the this to my ui.

while i call my context.resolve() i am getting the singletoninstnace however my listproperty() now is null..

am i missing something do expect it will preserve the  populatedata.

please enlighten.

Comment: Can you post some actual working/compilable code? Because it is hard to follow what are your trying to achieve and what is not working...

Comment: thanks nemesv, think it  was the bootstrap causing it. i m still looking through, but i guess my bootstrap is not really acting as class type(static)